# Cisco WebEx gives fatal error on launch

Tags: login, chat, webex, cisco-jabber

When I open Jabber, I get the messages:

```
'Fatal error occurred please contact Cisco WebEx Customer support'
'Can't load wbxOIEx.exe. Please check if the executable is installed in your directory.'
```

I am using Jabber Version 9.1.
I have upgraded Jabber to a new version, but still face the same issue

Comment: Is wbxOIEx.exe contained on your computer?

Comment: are u asking if wbxOIEx.exe is on the PC??

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 7.

1. Click on the Start menu, right-click on Computer, and select Properties.
2. Choose the link for Advanced System Settings, then go to the Advanced tab on the following page.
3. Click on the Settings button under Performance.
4. Go to the Data Execution Prevention tab.
5. Select the radio button for Turn on DEP for essential Windows programs and services only, then click OK.
6. Restart the computer for the changes to take effect.

Ref http://kb.webex.com/WBX41340